# How do I manually control Google Cardboard VR with data from Sensor Manager?

Tags: android, google-cardboard, virtual-reality, google-vr

I would like to manually pass data from Android Sensor Manager to Cardbard SDK for head control. Any ideas?

Thanks
Deepak